# web domain is not rendering JS via rendertron

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, web-crawler, rendertron

maybe I'm doing something wrong, i dont know. but ive got rendertron deployed to GCP and running. it works if i go to the https://garden-manager-XXXXX.appspot.com and put my domain url into the field and hit submit. but when i run my domain through google search console it still doesn't render the JS on the screenshot.

here is the code for rendertron thats deployed to GCP.

```
`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const rendertron = require('rendertron-middleware');

const BOTS = rendertron.botUserAgents.concat('googlebot');
const BOT_UA_PATTERN = new RegExp(BOTS.join('|'), 'i');

app.use(
rendertron.makeMiddleware({
proxyUrl: 'https://garden-manager-XXXXX.appspot.com/render',
userAgentPattern: BOT_UA_PATTERN,
})
);`
```

my domain name is [www.viewplants.com](http://www.viewplants.com) which is hosted on firebase under the same project id being used above for the rendertron.

am i missing something?